# AWS CloudFormation: How to get details on status reason in Events tab?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

it's extremely frustrating and impossible to debug my CF template when AWS CF only provides very little insight on why something's failed.

For example:

23:27:52 UTC-0700   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::IAM::Role  PeerRole    Resource creation cancelled

Is there no other way to find out exactly why a resource was cancelled? This is all I have to work with and it's not enough to determine a cause for why it happened.

```
"PeerRole": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [ {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ] },
                "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
            } ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [ {
            "PolicyName" : "PeerPrivs",
            "PolicyDocument" : {
                "Statement" : [{
                    "Effect" : "Allow",
                    "Action": [ "cloudwatch:PutMetricData", "cloudwatch:PutMetricDataBatch" ],
                    "Resource" : "*"
                },{
                    "Effect" : "Allow",
                    "Action" : [ "dynamodb:GetItem", "dynamodb:BatchGetItem", "dynamodb:Scan", "dynamodb:Query" ],
                    "Resource" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":table/", { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "stage", { "Ref" : "Stage" }, "ddbTable" ] } ] ]}
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}

    "PeerInstanceProfile": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
        "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "Roles": [{ "Ref": "PeerRole" }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: How are you invoking the execution ....through CLI or the console

Comment: @shibashis through the cli (using awscli from python) but not sure what difference that makes. This is the source code shell script that invokes it: https://github.com/vrivellino/clojure-west-2014-demo/blob/master/scripts/create-stack.sh

Comment: --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM are you passing the param as input when executing the script?

Comment: @Shibashis not sure what you mean. here's the original template https://github.com/vrivellino/clojure-west-2014-demo/blob/master/config/cfn-template.json

Comment: The template has creation of a IAM role and that's where your execution is failing. When you create IAM role through cloudformation you need to pass IAM capabilities. Please check the documetation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

Comment: @Shibashis I'm not sure, wasn't CAPABILITY_IAM itself the flag to set? Or did you mean to do `--capabilities=AWS::IAM::AccessKey , AWS::IAM::Group , AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile , AWS::IAM::Policy , AWS::IAM::Role , AWS::IAM::User , and AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition` instead?

Comment: just append "--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM" to your cli command that you are executing

Comment: @Shibashis but isn't that what that script is doing? `aws cloudformation create-stack \
 --stack-name "$2" \
 --template-body file://`dirname $0`/../config/cfn-template.json \
 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
 $parameters`

Comment: okay i did not see that earlier, i was just looking at the cf template

Comment: @Shibashis is there any way to get more insight into what is causing the IAM roles to fail to get created? maybe this is some version issue? this template is from 2014

Answer (score 1):

The error `Resource creation cancelled` means what it says - that the resource's creation has been cancelled. There are two typical reasons this might happen:

1. In response to a user-initiated request to [cancel the stack update](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn--stack-update-cancel.html).
2. If the stack update was automatically canceled due to a resource update failure. According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-monitor-stack.html),

> If a resource update fails, AWS CloudFormation rolls back any resources that it has updated during the upgrade to their configurations before the update.

So assuming you did not manually cancel the stack update yourself, then the underlying error that caused your stack creation/update to fail is actually in a different resource. View the stack event history in the `Events` tab of the Management Console or [using the CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-listing-event-history.html), and look for a `CREATE_FAILED` event occurring *before* the example error posted, and you will find the actual resource causing your stack creation to fail (which will likely be unrelated to the `AWS::IAM::Role` resource itself).

Comment: He already described having looked at the `CREATE_FAILED` event and didn't need help finding it. What he was asking was how to find additional detail when the "status reason" is vague. This did not answer the question.

Comment: @DeveloperDave the resource was cancelled because some other resource preceding it failed creation, causing the stack update to be cancelled. The additional detail can be found in a _different_ `CREATE_FAILED` event for that _other_ resource further up in the stack event history.